# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'

Tags: python, string, datetime

In the code below I'm trying to verify that a file dropped int a directory is a new file and should begin processing it.  I want to compare the creation date of the new file to the creation date of the last file processed.  This Last creation date is stored in a file on the directory(I'm open to better ideas of storing the date if you have them)  My problem is that the date stored in the file is a string and I'm not able to do a compare of the new date to the old date. The if statement at the bottom is what throws the error.The dates I'm comparing are **NewCreateTime is of type <class 'datetime.date'>
LastCreateTime is of type <class 'datetime.date'>**

How do I either convert both dates to datetime.objects or compare the datetime strings?

```
def is_file_ready(File_Name, Path, Ready, cTimeFile):
    NCTtstamp = path.getctime(File_Name)#create date of new file found in ready dir.
    NCTobj = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(NCTtstamp))
    NewCreateTime = datetime.strptime(NCTobj, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') 
    print('NewCreateTime is of type')
    print(type(NewCreateTime))
    
    LastCreateTimeFile = path.join('/', Path, Ready, cTimeFile)
    try:
        with open(LastCreateTimeFile, 'r') as lct: # get the last create time
            LCTline = lct.readline()
    except FileNotFoundError as fnferr:
        print('COULD NOT READ FILE!:\n', + File_Name + '\n\n', fnferr)

    LCTstr = LCTline.rstrip() 
    LastCreateTime = datetime.strptime(LCTstr, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    print('LastCreateTime is of type')
    print(type(LastCreateTime)) 
    if NewCreateTime > LastCreateTimeFile:
        
    if NewCreateTime > LastCreateTimeFile:
        return(NewCreateTime, True, LastCreateTime)
```

Comment: Typo: You want to compare with "LastCreateTime" but you use the file path "LastCreateTimeFile"

Comment: Thank you stared at it for too long and did not notice that.

Answer (score 0):

instead of comparing `NewCreateTime` with `LastCreateTime` you're comparing with `LastCreateTimeFile` which is not the same type.

change:

```
if NewCreateTime > LastCreateTimeFile:
```

to

```
if NewCreateTime > LastCreateTime:
```